# How to use a variable from one XSLT file to another

Tags: javascript, html, xslt

I have a scanario where I have to pass a variable for a javascript function in a xslt file.. Actually I have the value manipulated in another xslt file which I want to reuse here. I have given the sample of what I am tried. what I am doing wrong.

sub.xslt

```
.
.
    <xsl:variable name="textValuesCSV">
           <!-- some manipulation code -->
    </xsl:variable>
.
.
```

main.xslt

```
.
.
    <xsl:include href="sub.xslt"/>
    <xsl:template name="test">
        <script src="testScript.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">   
                  var name = "<xsl:value-of select="$textValuesCSV"/>";
           if(typeof analysis == 'function') { 
                analysis(name);
            }
        </script>   
    </xsl:template>
.
.
```

testScript.js

```
function analysis(name) {
   alert(name)
}
```

Comment: Did it fail? What was the error?

Answer (score 0):

You have to do the first variable declaration in main.xslt, just before calling the included xslt.
Then you can give the variable an updated value in sub.xslt .

Now the value will exist in the context of main.xslt, and you can call it in the javascript function.

P.S. the way you call the template depends on the XML input. If there is an element called `<test>` you want to trigger the template by `<xsl:apply-templates match="test"/>` in stead of `<xsl:call-template name="test"/>`
sub.xslt

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:variable name="textValuesCSV">1234</xsl:variable>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

main.xslt

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:variable name="textValuesCSV"/>
<xsl:include href="sub.xslt"/>

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <html>
         <xsl:call-template name="test"/>
      </html>
   </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="test">
        <xsl:copy  select="$textValuesCSV"/>
        <script src="testScript.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">   
           var name = "<xsl:value-of select="$textValuesCSV"/>";
           if(typeof analysis == 'function') {analysis(name);}
        </script>   
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output in DOM:

```
<document>
   <html>
      <script src="testScript.js"/>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        var name = "1234";
        if(typeof analysis == 'function') {analysis(name);}
      </script>
   </html>
```

Comment: is there any tool to work with it and get an DOM output as u have mentioned here ? if then pls tell me that

Comment: not working .. getting this error " A variable with no following sibling instructions has no effect "

Comment: which xslt engine do you use? The above solution was executed in both Firefox and Internet Explorer 11.

Comment: The edit-devil tricked me. Now use the edited code, the previous answer missed exactly the most essential variable declaration in main.xslt.